# The finite sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2}) \Gamma(a-k+ \frac{1}{2})} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I ran across a few finite sums involving the gamma function while doing some research about special cases of the hypergeometric function.

They're all very similar, so I'll just post one of them.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2}) \Gamma(a-k+ \frac{1}{2})} = \frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{n! \Gamma(n+ \frac{1}{2}) \Gamma(a)\Gamma(a+\frac{1}{2}) }$$

My first thought was just to write the sum as one big fraction and try to simplify. I didn't have much success doing that.

Perhaps the summand can be written in such a way that the terms of the series telescope.

Comment: By multiplying both sides with $n!$, the identity can be molded into something more aesthetically pleasing. But whether this will also prove helpful, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if that qualifies for an answer, but if you multiply both sides by $\Gamma\big(a+\frac{1}{2}\big)\,\Gamma\big(n+\frac{1}{2}\big)$, you get this:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{matrix}a-\frac{1}{2}\\k\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}n-\frac{1}{2}\\n-k\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}a+n-1\\n\end{matrix}\right)$$

which is a special case of the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity).

Here, when $b$ is a nonnegative integer, $\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\end{matrix}\right)$ is $\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{b!\,\Gamma(a-b+1)}$.

To prove

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{matrix}x\\k\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}y\\n-k\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}x+y\\n\end{matrix}\right)$$

for general complex $x$ and $y$, you start by fixing $x$ and considering this as a polynomial identity in $y$, so you only have to prove it for general complex $x$ and general integer $y\geq n$; then, fixing $y$, you only have to prove it for a general integer $x\geq n$.

It then follows from comparing the coefficients of $t^n$ in the expansions of $(1+t)^{x+y}$ and $(1+t)^x\,(1+t)^y$.